# Add vertical space before a \minipage

Tags: minipage

Is it possible to use a minipage with the a new line space before it in a single command?

```
Sample code here

\begin{minipage}[]{\linewidth}
\begin{minted}[linenos, frame=single]{java}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* code */
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

If I don't use minipage I get the expected result

```
Sample code here

\begin{minted}[linenos, frame=single]{java}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* code */
    }
}
\end{minted}
```

[image]

I would like to renew the minipage command (if it's possible) to add the new line before the minipage section. I'd prefer not to use `\\` after "Sample code here" if possible.

Comment: I might be overlooking your MWEs, but they both look exactly the same.

Comment: Right, my bad corrected!

Comment: Why do you need that `minipage` around the `minted` block?

Comment: Because if the code doesn't fit in the remaining page I don't want it to be displayed in a new page. I don't want the code to be splitted.

Comment: So the real question is to avoid page breaks within minted environments?

Comment: If it's not feasible to add a vertical space before the minipage then yes https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395967/142181

Comment: [Minted code on new page instead of splitting in half](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398571/37907)